# 3 Extruders on SKR V1.1, how set up 2 in 1 out (Y piece), and 1 single extruder in latest Marlin?

Tags: marlin, anet-a8

On Anet A8 with **SKR V1.1 32 bit board** my intention is to use **3 extruders** on my Anet A8, *1+2 via Y-piece on single nozzle*, 3rd Extruder with 2nd nozzle. Need another stepper to connect to SKR V1.1 (10 additional pins are available), extruder 1 + 2 go to single nozzle/heater via a Y-piece, 3rd extruder is on its own with own nozzle/heater. How to modify **latest Marlin** for this?? Please, all help appreciated, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Marlin, version 2.0.8, allows for multiple extruders (albeit with a single or multiple stepper motors) through a single nozzle, or multiple extruders with multiple nozzles, it is not possible with the current compiler definitions to configure a mixed extruder nozzle concept; this would require more changes to the sources.